# Appium unable to identify element using resource-id

Tags: appium, appium-android

Appium is unable to identify an element using the id locator(resource-id) instead we can identify the same using Accessibility Id locator.

Please refer to attached image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5lqE.png)

Comment: you didn't tell about App type - whether its a hybrid or native app?

Comment: Native app.....

Comment: Some time developer will set dynamic resource id to some elements,could you please check if resource id is changing or not. If id is same every time  you can try following code: driver.find_element_by_id("your_Element_ID") in this we have to search element by id as appium will consider resource-id as id .

Comment: Resource id is same all the time. 

But below does not work: 

driver.findElementById("rptRole__ctl0_rptCommunicationItems__ctl1_Repeater1__ctl0_dl_attachments__ctl0_lnk_attachment").click()

Below works:

driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("message_from_paul_mysay.pdf").click();

But problem with accessibility is that, it's dynamic so I can not use this. One thing I notice though is that resource-id does not starts with package name in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What is your version of Appium? Could you open it with Appium Inspector to check if there is any difference with UI Automator Viewer?

Anyway... Try this

```
#Can't see at your screenshot the whole resource-id so I put what I see.
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.view.View[@resource-id='rptRole__ctl0_rptCommunicationlt...']")

#You could also try these two options:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='1_gr_selected_stores_flex_update.xls']")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.view.View[@text='1_gr_selected_stores_flex_update.xls']")
```

If none of this work, you will have to provide more information

Comment: This does not work. I can not use content-desc field as this is dynamic. The only thing which I can use is resource id.
Appium version is 1.4.16.1. I am new to automation and have not used appium inspector yet. I am getting some error while starting inspector.

Comment: Appium does check for update when launched and says No update available. One thing I noticed is that the resouce-id does not starts with package name in this case. These links are .pdf/.xls file. If you get any clue.

Answer (score 1):

Appium doesn't support if you have some like $ in ID. Can you post your full ID.
Please try it with findElementById method as follow:

```
driver.findElementById("alertTitle");
```

If it is not working use class name to find element and use index to locate your element.

```
List<WebElement> allElements=driver.findElementsByClassName("android.view.View");
```

And get element using Index from above list.

```
WebElement yourElement= allElements.get(Required_Index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code works.

driver.findElementsByXPath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'rptRole')]").click();